# Java code for selecting date from Calendar pop-up

Tags: javascript, calendar, popup, selenium-webdriver

How to select date from calendar pop up? There's a text field which is in disabled mode. When you click on the calendar icon at the corner of the text field the calendar pops up which displays the current day-1 and current day-2 days as enabled to select and rest other dates disabled. I need to select the date from the above 2 days. How do i go about doing that in selenium java?

Below is the HTML Code for Calendar:

```
 <a href="javascript: fooCalendar.show()">
  <img width="16" height="14" border="0" src="images/dynCalendar.gif"/>
 </a>
 <div id="dynCalendar_layer_0" class="dynCalendar" onmouseout="fooCalendar._mouseover(false)"       
     onmouseover="fooCalendar._mouseover(true)" style="visibility: visible; top: 367px; left: 216px;">
     <table width="219" border="0" bgcolor="#DBE7F4">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <td width="219" colspan="7">
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="dynCalendar_dayname" width="27">Sun</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_dayname" width="27">Mon</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_dayname" width="27">Tue</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_dayname" width="27">Wed</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_dayname" width="27">Thu</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_dayname" width="27">Fri</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_dayname" width="27">Sat</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td/>
 <td/>
 <td/>
 <td/>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">1</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">2</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">3</td>
 </tr> 
 <tr>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">4</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">5</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">6</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">7</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">8</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">9</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_day" align="center">
 <a href="javascript: calendarSuspend(10, 8, 2013); fooCalendar._hideLayer()">10</a>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="dynCalendar_day" align="center">
 <a href="javascript: calendarSuspend(11, 8, 2013); fooCalendar._hideLayer()">11</a>
 </td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_today" align="center">12</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">13</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">14</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">15</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">16</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">17</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">18</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">19</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">20</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">21</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">22</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">23</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">24</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">25</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">26</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">27</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">28</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">29</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">30</td>
 <td class="dynCalendar_disabled" align="center">31</td>
 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 <table width="219" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Well first thing is get the current date. This would give you a head way. Next we can use a simple xpath subtracting a single or two days from the current date to select the actual date.

Comment: Get the current date. Once you do that subtract as many days in the range as you want. For ex if you want to select 2 days previous to the current date then subtract 2. Once you get the number pass it to the following xpath //td[text() = 'yourdate'] and perform the click operation.

Comment: @Vinay 
Also need to select a range of days (between current day and Current day-7. Please suggest how to accomplish this. But don't know how to send the date in the text field that need to be filled with the date in "MM/DD/YYYY" format.I have tried using the following:     
     `Calendar javaCalendar = null;
     String currentDate = " ";
     javaCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     currentDate = javaCalendar.get(Calendar.DATE) + "/" +            
       (javaCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" +   
       javaCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);`

Comment: You can't just type the date as you have said the filed is disabled. If it's enabled then you can simply use sendkeys method to type the date in any format.

Comment: Can we use send keys to pass the whole string or do we need to parse it to send it to the text field. If we need to parse to which type we need to do that?

Comment: And it should be like we should click on a date in the Calendar pop up and the date should appear in the text box field.